# what is Vercel Edge Runtime exactly?

Tags: vercel, edge-runtime

I read officual document about vercel edge runtime at https://edge-runtime.vercel.app/

but I don't understand at all about what it is.

as I know, this runtime is not Node.js. but why they said like `It runs everywhere Node.js does`?

It is not related with node.js , isn't it ?

I want concrete explanation about this, not abstract explanation like official docs said.

thank you